# preserve policy tag on bigquery table schema after write_Truncate

Tags: google-bigquery

I am etling (pentaho tool) a table in write_truncate mode and i need to mask one column (email) for a group(say A), I am able to do it through a policy tag. Problem is every time the table refreshes it drops policy tag from table hence masking does not work.

I see in bigquery, write_truncate mode will drop schema. Is there a work around to automatically update schema whenever the table get refreshed, So that this column is masked for group A all time.

Thank you
Sunita

Note: I tried the policy tag it works as expected untill table refreshes.